# Why did gem install bson_ext fail on Windows?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bson-ext

I got this error when I install bson_ext on Windows.

The error message is:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bson_ext:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for asprintf()... no
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
checking for ruby/regex.h... yes
checking for ruby/encoding.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
generating cbson-i386-mingw32.def
compiling bson_buffer.c
compiling cbson.c
cbson.c:150:15: warning: extra tokens at end of #ifdef directive
cbson.c: In function 'pack_extra':
cbson.c:201:27: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
cbson.c: In function 'write_element':
cbson.c:211:28: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
cbson.c:317:17: warning: implicit declaration of function '_scprintf'
compiling encoding_helpers.c
linking shared-object bson_ext/cbson.so
c:/devkit/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt-ru
by191
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [cbson.so] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bson_ext-1.9.1     for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bson_ext1.9.1/ext/cbson/gem_make.out
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I have seen the same question on stackoverflow, but it seem a little bit different form mine, it happened on Linux, and mine is happened on windows, I donot know the difference between them, and the same question is:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632181/error-installing-bson-ext

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092541/windows-rails-error-installing-bson-ext